# Paypal Express Checkout window keeps loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, paypal, express-checkout

I'm trying to integrate the PayPal button to execute a simple payment to a new Paypal account I just created.
Following the guide I rendered the button, but when I click on it and the new window shows up, nothing happens. The "loading lock" keeps spinning, but no errors are shown in the new window, nor in my page. No calls to "onError()" function are executed. I don't know what's wrong! I followed the instruction of the guide!

Navigating other websites I saw that in the new window, while loading (and the "loading lock" spins) some get/post are executed, nothing is executed in my case.

This is my HTML and related .js file (well, part of them)

```js
//THIS FUNCTION IS CALLED TO DISPLAY A NEW ELEMENT CONTAINING THE BUTTON 
function payment(todelete) {

    destroy(todelete);
    $("#pay").delay(timeFade).fadeIn(timeFade);
    
    paypal.Button.render({
        env: 'sandbox',
        client: {
            sandbox:    'MYKEY',
            production: 'MYKEY'
        },

        commit: true,

        payment: function(data, actions) {
            fetch("/getOldAmount").then(function(res){
                return (res.json());
            }).then(function(data){

                var old_amount = data[0].Donation;
                var amount_tot = $("#amount").val();
                //BUILDING A RANDOM TEST JSON, NOT RELATED TO MY CODE
                var payment_json = {
                        transactions: [
                            {
                                amount: {
                                    total:    '1.00',
                                    currency: 'USD'
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    };
                if(amount_tot > old_amount){
                //WHEN CLICKING PAYPAL BUTTON I CAN SEE THIS LOG, SO EVERYTHING IS FINE HERE
                    console.log("EXECUTING PAYPAL POST");
                    return actions.payment.create(payment_json);
                } else {
                    console.log("Amount too low to execute transaction");
                }

            });
        },

        onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.payment.execute().then(function(payment) {
                console.log("AUTHORIZED");
            });
        },
        onError: function(data, actions){
            console.log("ERRORRRRRR");
            console.log(data);
        }

    }, '#paypal-button');
    
}
```

```html
<div class="container pagination-centered" style="display: block">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="richest_header" for="amount">ENTER AMOUNT</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control amount-field" id="amount" placeholder="Amount..." name="amountField">
            </div>
            <div id="paypal-button"></div>
</div>

<!-- HEADER -->
    [...]
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/script/myscript.js"></script>
    [...]
```

Do I need to do something more? 
Do I need to add code? 
Am I doing something wrong?
Why is paypal documentation so poor?

Comment: `but no errors are shown in the new window, nor in my page` - does this refer to the browser **developer** tools console? i.e. no errors there? You've tried multiple browsers (Firefox, Chrome, IE, Edge etc)? All behave the same? Do you need to return something other than a promise that resolved to undefined in `onAuthorize`?

Comment: are you launching the file from localhost or just file:/// ?

Comment: Sorry for low details.
I refer to the console of every page, the page where I set the button and the new window PayPal creates to initiate payment. 
I'm specifying this because when I do something wrong (e.g. build a json not well formed) the call executed by the button returns an error (e.g. "Bad Request" ), but now nothing happens.
I've tried all browsers I have, Firefox, Edge, Chrome and Internet Explorer.
Every time same old story.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the promise to `payment()` -- `return fetch("/getOldAmount").then(...`

Comment: ...this is the exact reason they see the loading spinner. They're not returning the promise, so the popup has no idea when to show the checkout experience.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'll try to do it and I'll let you know if that was the problem ;)

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked!!!!
Can you explain me what was wrong and why?

Comment: Sure! so that `payment()` function needs you to pass back a promise -- that's how it eventually gets the payment id it needs to launch the url in the iframe. In your case, since the promise wasn't being returned, the `payment()` function just got `undefined` which meant it didn't have enough context to start the checkout flow properly.

Comment: Thank you for the explaination!