# PayPal Express Checkout JS - Window Keeps Loading

Tags: javascript, paypal

I am implementing PayPal Express Checkout with a custom online store. These attempts are happening on a live server.

There are no error shown in the Developer Console, the PayPal window that opens just keeps loading with the Lock Symbol.

In all of my research, I have found this answer to be the one that defines the issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47446311

In another application that I have integrated with PayPal, I tried removing the "Return" and had the same symptoms as I am having with this application. But in this application, I have clearly added the "Return".

Any help is appreciated!

Here is the code Sample:

```
paypal.Button.render({
      env: 'sandbox', // 'production' Or 'sandbox',

      commit: true, // Show a 'Pay Now' button

      client: {
      sandbox:    'SANDBOX-ID',
      production: 'PRODUCTION-ID'
    },

      style: {
        color: 'gold',
        size: 'medium'
      },

      payment: function(data, actions) {
        /* 
         * Set up the payment here 
         */
                //Cart Calculation Total...
        var pptotal = document.getElementById('final_price').innerHTML.replace('$','');

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
          // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {  // code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
          if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
            //console.log(this.responseText);
            var r = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            //Setup variables for payment...
            if(r.response === 'GOOD'){
              pp_payment.payment = {};
              pp_payment.payment.transactions = [];
              var trans_obj = {};
              trans_obj.amount = {};
              trans_obj.amount.total = parseFloat(pptotal).toFixed(2);
              trans_obj.amount.currency = "USD";
              trans_obj.description = "Purchase Details";
              trans_obj.item_list = {};
              var items_array = [];
              var items_obj = {};

              var icount = r.item.length;
              for(var i = 0; i < icount; i++){
                var x = r.item[i];
                items_obj.name = x.pname;
                items_obj.quantity = x.pqty;
                items_obj.price = parseFloat(x.pprice).toFixed(2);
                items_obj.tax = "0.00";
                items_obj.sku = x.pid;
                items_obj.currency = "USD";
                items_array.push(items_obj);
                var items_obj = {};
              }
              trans_obj.item_list.items = items_array;
              pp_payment.payment.transactions.push(trans_obj);



              return actions.payment.create(pp_payment);

            }else{
              console.warn('An Error occurred while calculating the cart');
              alert('An Error occurred while calculating the cart');
            }

          }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","my-cart/php/get-cart-items.php",true);
        xmlhttp.send();

        //End Cart Calculation.

      },
```

EDIT:

I have made the switch to the new PayPal Smart Buttons API as suggested, and now it is throwing an error: `Uncaught Error: Expected an order id to be passed`

When I use this same code snippet (Below) in the PayPal API Tester here: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client I dont have any errors at all.

Wondering what I am doing wrong?

```
// Render the PayPal button into #paypal-button-container
paypal.Buttons({

  // Set up the transaction
  createOrder: function(data, actions) {

    //Cart Calculation...
    var rpptotal = document.getElementById('final_price').innerHTML.replace('$', '');
    var pptotal = parseFloat(rpptotal).toFixed(2);

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
        var r = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        //Setup variables for payment...
        if (r.response === 'GOOD') {
          pp_payment.purchase_units = [];
          var trans_obj = {};
          //trans_obj.orderID = getRandomNumber(100000,999999);
          trans_obj.amount = {};
          trans_obj.amount.value = pptotal;
          //trans_obj.amount.currency_code = "USD";
          trans_obj.amount.breakdown = {};
          trans_obj.amount.breakdown.item_total = {};
          trans_obj.amount.breakdown.item_total.value = pptotal;
          trans_obj.amount.breakdown.item_total.currency_code = "USD";
          //trans_obj.description = "Purchase Details";
          trans_obj.items = [];
          var items_array = [];
          var items_obj = {};

          var icount = r.item.length;
          for (var i = 0; i < icount; i++) {
            var x = r.item[i];
            items_obj.name = x.pname;
            items_obj.unit_amount = {};
            items_obj.quantity = x.pqty;
            items_obj.unit_amount.value = x.pprice;
            //items_obj.tax = "0";
            items_obj.sku = x.pid;
            items_obj.unit_amount.currency_code = "USD";
            trans_obj.items.push(items_obj);
            var items_obj = {};
          }
          //trans_obj.items = items_array;
          //pp_payment['purchase_units'].push(trans_obj);
          pp_payment.purchase_units.push(trans_obj);
          console.log(pp_payment);
          console.log(JSON.stringify(pp_payment));
          //pp_payment = JSON.stringify(pp_payment);
          //End Payment Variable Setup.

          return actions.order.create(pp_payment);

        } else {
          console.warn('An Error occurred while calculating the cart');
          alert('An Error occurred while calculating the cart');
        }
      }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "my-cart/php/get-cart-items.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  },

  // Finalize the transaction
  onApprove: function(data, actions) {
    alert('APPROVED');
    return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
      // Show a success message to the buyer
      alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
    });
  }


}).render('#paypal-button');
```

Comment: You appear to be using an old/archived version of PayPal's checkout.js , so my first suggestion would be to switch to the latest Smart Payment Buttons javascript client and see if you have better results. Here is a skeleton demo: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: @PrestonPHX I made the switch and am having a different issue now [Outlined in my edit]. Any suggestions?

Comment: What server-side API are you using? SetExpressCheckout or similar? Try setting `trans_obj.orderID` to be the unique ID of whatever your server is returning for the checkout

Comment: @PrestonPHX, I don’t have a Server Side API setup with this, I am just using what PayPal returns and inputing the info into my database for my own record keeping. Does this version of PayPal require a server-side API in addition? I wasn’t aware of it. I have attempted setting the `trans_obj.orderID` equal to a random generated ID and I am having the same error response.

Comment: Oh, well in that case you need the client-side integration pattern: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

Comment: @PrestonPHX, That is what I integrated with and am still receiving the error.

Comment: Then post a simple, testable example of that integration that reproduces your issue.. Include the <script> tag. Omit any xmlhttp stuff that distracts from the issue. Make you example be as close to the code at http://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client as possible, changing only what is necessary to reproduce the error.

Comment: @PrestonPHX Many thanks for your help. I just found the issue and got it corrected. I will be posting my correction shortly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error, I was able to find the cause of my issue.

It seems that having an XHR request within the function of `createOrder` caused a de-synchronization of the returned data from PayPal. (Not too sure on the exact reason for this, but it was the issue)

The XHR Request is necessary in order to build the payment JSON object that is needed to pass to the `actions.order.create()` function. I just built a simple function that housed the XHR request and added an additional step in the UI (a button "Continue to Checkout") which called this function to build the payment object and open up the rendered PayPal Checkout button.

Once I put the XHR request outside of the `createOrder` function, all functions properly!

Here is the updated code:

```
var pp_payment = {};
var ppitems;

//Random Number Generator...
function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

function prepare_order(){
  //Cart Calculation...
    var rpptotal = document.getElementById('final_price').innerHTML.replace('$', '');
    var pptotal = parseFloat(rpptotal).toFixed(2);

    pp_payment = {};//Clear the pp_payment variable...

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
        var r = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        //Setup variables for payment...
        if (r.response === 'GOOD') {
          pp_payment.purchase_units = [];
          var trans_obj = {};
          trans_obj.amount = {};
          trans_obj.amount.value = pptotal;
          trans_obj.amount.breakdown = {};
          trans_obj.amount.breakdown.item_total = {};
          trans_obj.amount.breakdown.item_total.value = pptotal;
          trans_obj.amount.breakdown.item_total.currency_code = "USD";
          trans_obj.items = [];
          var items_array = [];
          var items_obj = {};

          var icount = r.item.length;
          for (var i = 0; i < icount; i++) {
            var x = r.item[i];
            items_obj.name = x.pname;
            items_obj.unit_amount = {};
            items_obj.quantity = x.pqty;
            items_obj.unit_amount.value = x.pprice;
            items_obj.sku = x.pid;
            items_obj.unit_amount.currency_code = "USD";
            trans_obj.items.push(items_obj);
            var items_obj = {};
          }
          pp_payment.purchase_units.push(trans_obj);
          console.log('Order Created...');
          console.log(pp_payment);
          //End Payment Variable Setup.

          document.getElementById('pre-pp-btn').style.display = 'none';
          document.getElementById('paypal-button').style.display = 'inline';

        } else {
          console.warn('An Error occurred while calculating the cart');
          alert('An Error occurred while calculating the cart');
        }
      }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "my-cart/php/get-cart-items.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

// Render the PayPal button into #paypal-button-container
paypal.Buttons({

  // Set up the transaction
  createOrder: function(data, actions) {
    return actions.order.create(pp_payment);
  },

  // Finalize the transaction
  onApprove: function(data, actions) {
    alert('APPROVED');
    return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
      // Show a success message to the buyer
      alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
    });
  }


}).render('#paypal-button');
```